# I cannot change the value of an integer using pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Here is the code I'm running:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *p;
    p = &x;
    *p++;
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be 6, because `p` is pointing at the address of `x`. However, I get 5.

But more interestingly, I couldn't understand why the output is 6 when I change `*p++` with `*p = *p+1`. Why is this?

Comment: [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: `(*p)++;` or `++*p;` , `*p++` meant `*p` and then `p++`

Comment: As @chris said. Try `++*p` or `*p+=1`. Or enclose `*p` in parens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are wrong. *p++ reads the value that p points to, then increases the pointer p. You probably wanted (*p)++.

*p = *p + 1 works because it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)`; IOW, you're incrementing the pointer, not the thing being pointed to.

Use `(*p)++` to increment the thing being pointed to, or use `++*p`.

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets if you do not understand operator precedence.

```
*p++
```

is

```
*(p++)
```

and you want

```
(*p)++
```

The rule of thumb is:

- multiplication and division go before addition and subtraction
- for everything else, just use brackets

Comment: This is a horrible advice. The answer is: Learn precedence rules. You need be able to read other people's code and e.g. `while(*t++ = *s++);` is a totally valid and idiomatic way to copy a 0-terminated array.

Comment: @mafso sure, if you do not mind buffer overflow errors.  Such code, if in performance critical regions, needs rewriting to be faster (branch on every value?  copy one value at a time?) or a pile of comments proving its safety, or replacement with more robust code.  Understanding precidence rules enough so you can fix bug prone code like that is useful, I will admit.

Comment: I didn't intend to advise to use that code (not for reasons of readability, but because the cases where you don't know the length of the source but have a target you know being big enough to hold the copy are rather rare, and this is true for most `str*` function usages, where I most often wouldn't advise their use either, but still, you have to _know_ them), but that wasn't my point. I think it's necessary to understand such constructs. And putting parentheses around _every_ expression not being the result of either binary `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` would lead to unnecessarily hard to read code.